# what is the best structure for developing a sortable multilevel list?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I need to develop a good table structure for creating a **sortable** multilevel list using SQL Server Database.

Here is an example of the way I develop sortable multilevel lists:

```
A
├──B
|  ├──E
|  ├──F
|  ├──O
|
├──C
|  ├──M
|
```

My table structure:

```
ID   Title   Parent   Sort
---------------------------
1    A       Null     0
2    B       A        0
3    E       B        0
4    F       B        1
5    O       B        2
6    C       A        1
7    M       C        0
```

Now, would you mind telling me the **best way** of developing such lists?
Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: There is never "best way", only "most suitable for current requirements". And requirements you have given are few. What operations will be done on this strucure? How often? Number of items? Depth of nesting. Required speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go with your outlined structure. SQL Server supports recursive queries via CTEs, something like this will do the trick for you:

```sql
WITH tree AS (
  SELECT id, name, parent,
         0 AS level,
         CAST(sort AS varchar(90)) AS path,
         CAST(name AS varchar(90)) AS fullname
    FROM test WHERE parent IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.id, t.name, t.parent, tree.level + 1,
         CAST(tree.path + '.' + CAST(t.sort AS varchar) AS varchar(90)),
         CAST(tree.fullname + '.' + t.name AS varchar(90))
    FROM test t
    JOIN tree ON t.parent = tree.name
)
SELECT id, name, parent, level, path, fullname FROM tree
ORDER BY path;
```

I'm building some extra informative fields here:

- `level`, indicating depth of the node from the root;
- `path`, which is built based on your `sort` field and is used to sort the tree properly;
- `fullname` — just a nice view on the full node name.

You can try this query [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e3e1/9).

Please, consider the size of your data — for huge data structures you might want to push predicates into the inner query for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Design ONE table with all required details, add ID and ParentID, Right outer join ParentID on ID. Done.